# Python 3 And PyQt6 with DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to get data from My maria DB using PyQt6.
its not working

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._table_view = QTableView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._table_view)

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        
        self.db.setHostName("127.0.0.1")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("secqtydb")
        self.db.setUserName("root")
        self.db.setPassword("1234")
        print("db is - ", self.db.open())
        self.db.open()
        
        self.qry = "SELECT * FROM files"
        self.query = QSqlQuery()
        print("query2 is-- ", self.query.prepare(self.qry))
        self.query.prepare(self.qry)
        self.query.exec()
        

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(self.query.result()):
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, self._table_view(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

self.bd.open() i get true
but self.query.prepare(self.qry) i get False
please help someone

where is no tutorial for PyQt6
i tried to look on the web but i found Tutorials only for PyQt5

Comment: MariaDB is not Sqlite. Also, try to avoid multiple calls just for print/debugging, as not all functions behave in the same way if called more than once (and if they do, it's unnecessary). Finally, Qt6 is not that different from Qt5, especially for well established modules: most of what you find for PyQt5 will work fine in PyQt6 as well. Just be aware of important [differences](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pyqt5_differences.html) (notably, the usage of enums) and eventually check the official Qt documentation (**not** the "Qt for Python" one, which is often unreliable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're trying to connect to a MariaDB database using PyQt6.

Few issues in your code that need to be addressed:

- You're using the SQLite driver `("QSQLITE")` for your `QSqlDatabase`, but you should be using the MariaDB driver `("QMYSQL")`. [Ref -https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html)

**Note : `QMYSQL` driver will not be available mostly. you have to manually download the dlls and try it**

- You should create a `QSqlTableModel`  or `QSqlQueryModel`  to work with your database data and populate the `QTableView`.

'''

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._table_view = QTableView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._table_view)

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")  
        self.db.setHostName("127.0.0.1")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("secqtydb")
        self.db.setUserName("root")
        self.db.setPassword("1234")

        if self.db.open():
            print("Connected to the database")

            self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
            self.model.setTable("files")  # Set the table name

            if self.model.select():
                self._table_view.setModel(self.model)
            else:
                print("Failed to select data from the table")

        else:
            print("Failed to connect to the database")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, everything is working. To fix Drivers just needed to run "pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyqt6"

Comment: @BennyLutin - Thanks for the update. It helped me too about force the reinstall.